# Javascript function first execute and return value, before proceedng

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a React application where I first want to make sure that both of my JWT token are set prior continuing the application (componentDidMount lifecycle hook). I used a callback to make certain that the second function awaits the first function. but for some reason the value is not in my localstorage yet. I cannot use redux for this, as the first two calls that I am fetching are user images.

All hints/advise is welcome. Thanks.

app.js

```
  componentWillMount() {


  function firstFunction(_callback){
      acquireToken();
      acquireGraphToken();
      _callback();    
  }

    function secondFunction(){
      firstFunction(function() {
          console.log('huzzah, I\'m done!');
      });  
    }

      secondFunction();
  }
```

ADAL.JS (Which handles my token requests.)

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch } from 'react-adal';

const adalConfig = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    clientId: '*******',
    extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
    endpoints: {
        graphApi: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
        oneApi: 'https://one365demo.onmicrosoft.com/b153b2*********-3f1d0cf658f5'
    },
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);



export const adalGraphFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.graphApi, fetch, url, options);

export const adalOneApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.oneApi, fetch, url, options);





export const getToken = () => {
    return authContext.getCachedToken(authContext.config.clientId);
};

export const getGraphToken = () => {
    return authContext.getCachedToken('https://graph.microsoft.com');
};




export const acquireGraphToken = () => {  
    authContext.acquireToken(adalConfig.endpoints.graphApi, (message, token, msg) => {
        console.log('graph token', token);
        return token;
    })

    return null;
} 

export const acquireToken = () => {  
    authContext.acquireToken(adalConfig.endpoints.oneApi, (message, token, msg) => {
        console.log('the token', token);
        return token;
    })

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `comonentDidMount` is not intended to "pause" execution. Requests are asynchronous. Code exection should and will continue on the client. Never block the ui while waiting for an expensive task. If you want to await a response prior to continuing render e.g. a spinner, start the request and replace the spinner with content when you evaluated the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `render()` method evaluates once in a very early moment, **before** `componentWillMount()`. Then it is reevaluated (in principle) every time the component state is changed **via the `setState` method**.

What I usually do is to mark in the component's state when the initialization is completed, and check for this mark in the `render()` method. In your example:

```
componentWillMount() {
  function firstFunction(_callback){
      acquireToken();
      acquireGraphToken();
      _callback();    
  }

  function secondFunction(){
    firstFunction(function() {
        console.log('huzzah, I\'m done!');
        this.setState({dataIsReady: true})
    });  
  }

  secondFunction();
}


render() {
  if (this.state.dataIsReady) {
    // render the actual app
  } else {
    // render some "Loading ..." message
  }
}
```

Hope it helps - Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You should create a value in the state to track your preliminary function completion. Just change the value, and then have the component load as normal.

e.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { shouldLoad: false }

  firstFunction() {
    //Execute your functions here then...

    //Set state when complete...
    this.setState({ shouldLoad: true });
  }

  render() {
    const {shouldLoad} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {shouldLoad === true && (
          <p>Load your content here</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```